# Python/NumPy - Tail letter placement algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to write a program that correctly centers handwritten letters in a similar fashion to Microsoft Word. Using a standard handwriting grid for comparison, the bottom of the letter is placed right on the lowest gridline for most letters: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gncW.png).

However, there are five tail letters where this doesn't apply: g, j, p, q, and y. For these letters, the bottom of the letter goes below the lowest gridline:
 [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbSrg.png).

I want to find the distance between the bottom of the letter and the lowest gridline for these tail letters. The letter images themselves don't come with gridlines drawn in, and are stored as binary numpy array-files. I need some way to algorithmically determine the vertical location of this lowest gridline, but I'm not sure where to begin.